# Unusual 3x3 square

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

Can you fill a 3x3 grid with every number from 1 to 9, such that the sum of numbers in the first row is equal to the sum of numbers in every 2x2 sub-grid? Can you find multiple solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, here's one:

> 7 1 9
>     5 4 3
>     6 2 8